# Gradle/maven/Java/IntelliJ how to handle lots of resource files (several thousand)?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a lot of XML files (60000+) that I'm putting in my `src/main/resources/xmlFiles` directory but when I run any of my tests or main class files, the build takes longer than usual to run. On first run after a `gradle clean`, the `processResources` task take 1 minute and 10 seconds+ to copy 32 MB worth of 60k+ XML files. Subsequent runs only take 5 seconds to start the program or tests, but it still slow. I assume it is because it is checking the status for each xml file in my resources folder to see if it needs to copy the file into the `build` folder? These XML files are never changing.

I looked online and I saw some suggestions to zip the thousands of resource files into a jar file, and read the XML files from inside the jar file, but no matter what I try, I cannot get it to work either. I put the xml file in the root folder of the jar file, so `getClass().getResourceAsStream("myFile.xml")` should apparently work, but it doesn't, I get a `null` when running this. If I try `getClass().getResourceAsStream("xmlFiles.jar")` I'm able to load the jar file itself, but I thought you don't need to do this? I thought it unzips/unpacks the jar file when you call `getResourceAsStream()` and you can get the file directly inside without needing to read the jar file? I also tried `getClass().getResourceAsStream("xmlFiles.jar/myFile.xml")` but this doesn't work either. Also, in IntelliJ, I tried right clicking on the jar file containing my xml files and adding it as a library, which it seemingly unpacks the jar file and I can see all my files now, but I still cannot access them directly using `getResourceAsStream()`. The JAR file doesn't contain any class files, just XML files, not sure if it's necessary to have class files in a jar file for it to work?

I'm just wondering what the best approach is for handling a lot of files (or large resource files) in java/gradle/maven? I don't think I'm the first one to encounter this issue but I cannot seem to find any relevant results in Google.

Comment: This isn't really related, but: What are you doing with 60,000+ XML resources?